# Drivers for Matrox P690 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xorg

Has anyone got a P690 working on Xenial?

I have some Dell T610 servers which are to be used as number crunching workstations. They come standard with a Matrox G200 which is uninspiring as a graphics card. I have bought Matrox P690 PCIe x1 cards for each but am struggling with the drivers. The package mtxdriver-installer-x86_64-cvs-20090511.run is as the date suggests, pretty old and the scripts and make files anticipate a maximum Xorg version of 1.4 and linux kernel of 2.7. They also anticipate quite a different directory structure to that used by 16.04. I am working through the script and make files to point them in the right places however several of the subroutines are now producing warnings leading to errors and not compiling. Mostly syntax things like assigning pointers in declarations and stuff that I can only think gcc didn't used to complain about. The worry is that I don't even know if once compiled they will be compatible with the kernel but for the moment I slug on.

To pre-empt any questions about what I see at the moment - I have one test machine set up with a dual head 60 pin to twin DVI adapter, each DVI with a monitor attached. Ubuntu is only giving me one monitor at a '70s resolution of 640x480. lspci shows the card as a Matrox Millenium P690. I'm running Xorg 1.18 and a 4.4 kernel. There is no Xorg.conf file but that was dropped a few versions ago.

Any tips or pointers from others that have done similar (and succeeded) would be welcome.

Comment: You may try installing `xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-xenial` as suggested in this Italian forum: http://www.istitutomajorana.it/forum2/Thread-RISOLTO-Scheda-grafica-Matrox-P690-Ubuntu-14-04-MATE-compiz-3D-x64-Systemback

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks but no joy I'm afraid. I did a similar thing to get the G200 base graphics to work in the first instance but it does not look like the Xorg mga team have got to the P690. I'll spend some time trawling the FAQs there and see if I get a clue.

Comment: OK I've had to admit defeat and get some NVidia cards instead. For anyone else going down this road, I modified the code, makefile and install script to get it to compile and install but the object code in the installation/xserver directory has version info in it so Xorg rejects the driver when it loads because of ABI version mismatch, 2 vs 9! If anyone thinks they can do better and wants the edited versions of the script, makefile and code let me know and I'll pass it on.